# Error: Could not find or load main class io.gatling.app.Gatling

Tags: linux, scala, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

Getting *Error: Could not find or load main class io.gatling.app.Gatling* while running a jar for performance test,but works fine when I run the same code on intellij
Below are the Sample steps for the execution of code

Step:1
Created a mvn package of PerformanceTest.jar using Gatling.

**SampleTestPlayer.scala**

```
package com.performance.SampleTest
import com.performance.config.ScenarioConfiguration
import com.performance.{Player, Feeders}
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.{ChainBuilder, ScenarioBuilder}
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

class SampleTestPlayer extends SomeClass {

  val config: ScenarioConfiguration.type = ScenarioConfiguration
  gdmServerEndpoint = config.gdmServerUrl
  Name = config.Name

  val regexGsdViewArea = "VA~(?:[\\d\\|]+?)+"


  def play(): ChainBuilder = {
    exec(http(TEST)
      .post(ServerEndpoint)
      .body(StringBody(session => bodyXml(session, config.Name,
        prepareRequest(session, config.Name, 10, 5))))
      .check(status.is(200)
        , regex("<SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>").exists
        , regex(errorMsgId).notExists
        , regex(errorProtocol).optional.saveAs(errorProtocol)
      )
    )
      .exec(checkForErrors)
      .pause(requestsInterval)
     
  }


  val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("SampleTest_Performance_Tests")
    .feed(Feeders.operator1UsersFeeder)
    .exec({ session => session.set("recoverAfterRequest", false)})
    .repeat(config.numPlays) {
      play()
    }

  if (config.model == "closed") {
    setUp(
      scn.inject(
        rampUsers(config.numUsers) during (config.rampUpDuration)
      ).protocols(buildHttpConf(config.baseUrl))
    )
  }

  if (config.model == "open") {
    setUp(
      scn.inject(
        nothingFor(4 seconds), // 1
        atOnceUsers(10), // 2
        rampUsers(5) during (20 seconds), // 3
        constantUsersPerSec(2) during (15 seconds), // 4
        constantUsersPerSec(2) during (15 seconds) randomized, // 5
        rampUsersPerSec(2) to 5 during (1 minutes), // 6
        rampUsersPerSec(2) to 5 during (1 minutes) randomized, // 7
        heavisideUsers(100) during (20 seconds) // 8
      ).protocols(buildHttpConf(config.baseUrl))
    )
  }
}constantUsersPerSec(2) during (15 seconds) randomized, // 5
        rampUsersPerSec(2) to 5 during (1 minutes), // 6
        rampUsersPerSec(2) to 5 during (1 minutes) randomized, // 7
        heavisideUsers(100) during (20 seconds) // 8
      ).protocols(buildHttpConf(config.baseUrl))
    )
  }
}
```

**SampleTestRunner.scala**

```
package com.performance.SampleTest

import io.gatling.app.Gatling
import io.gatling.core.config.GatlingPropertiesBuilder

object SampleTestRunner {



  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    System.setProperty("baseUrl", "https://SomeUrl")

    System.setProperty("Name", "SampleTest")
  
    System.setProperty("requestsInterval", "1000")

    val simulationClass = classOf[SampleTestPlayer].getName

    val props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder
    props.simulationClass(simulationClass)

    Gatling.fromMap(props.build)
  }
}
```

Step:2
Create a launch.sh file to run these test.

**launch.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
USER_ARGS="-Dsomething=$1"
COMPILATION_CLASSPATH=`find -L . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jar" -type f -exec printf :{} ';'`
JAVA_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false ${JAVA_OPTS} -DName=sampletest -DbaseUrl=https://SomeUrl -DnumPlays=100 -Dmodel=closed -DnumUsers=1000 -DrequestsInterval=10000 -DrampUpDuration=3000"
java $JAVA_OPTS $USER_ARGS -cp $COMPILATION_CLASSPATH io.gatling.app.Gatling -s com.performance.sampletest.SampleTestPlayer
```

Comment: Honestly, you're hacking Gatling internals at your own risks. Gatling has a set of official launchers: zip bundle, maven, sbt, gradle (official plugin will be coming in 3.4.0) and FrontLine.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I'm using the gradle pulgin and I'm missing the feature to bundle it as a jar and run it remotely on a server. What is the benefit of just having a gradle task "gatlingRun" to run it? As of now it is just nice to play with on an IDE.

Comment: @YounesEO The gradle plugin lets you start Gatling tests with a gradle project from the command line. It has nothing to do with an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to start the tests where the -jar jar_name command was missing.

**Note:** That the environment variables (starting with -D) come first and then it’s the jar and then the Player (java <environment_variables> -jar perf_tests.jar -s PlayerClass

```
#!/bin/sh
USER_ARGS="-Dsomething=$1"
COMPILATION_CLASSPATH=`find -L . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jar" -type f -exec printf :{} ';'`
JAVA_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false 
java -DbaseUrl=https://SomeUrl -DnumPlays=100 -Dmodel=closed -DnumUsers=1000 -DrequestsInterval=3000 -jar performance-tests-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -s com.performance.sampletest.SampleTestPlayer
```