# Build Executable Jar with Gradle for Gatling

Tags: scala, gradle, jar, gatling

### The Problem

I've created a Scala and Gatling project with which I want to perform some load test. The idea is that I build an executable jar, which I then simply execute to run said load test.

I have so far no problems running the load test in my IDE. However, when I try to assemble it with:

```
gradle assemble
```

The jar is empty i.e. contains my utility classes from `src/main/scala`, but nothing from `src/gatling/*` (see below for my setup).

I've experimented with fat jars but that task gives me the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':fatJar'.
> Cannot expand ZIP 'D:\projects\load-test\build\classes\java\main' as it does not exist.
```

I have no idea why it expects java in the first place.

### My Setup

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
load-test/
├── src/
│   ├── gatling/
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── scala
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── scala
│   └── test/
│       ├── resources
│       └── scala
├── ...
└── build.gradle
```

I've found out, that the Gatling plugin is very stubborn and it only includes the Gatling depencies in `gatlingCompileClasspath`. So In order to be able to write a loadtest, I need to have a `gatling` sourceset. The `main/scala` dir is used to implement some utility functions such as creating custom timestamps etc. `test/scala` tests those.

My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.maiflai.scalatest" version "0.25"
    id 'io.gatling.gradle' version "3.4.0"
    id "scala"
}

apply plugin: "scala"
apply plugin: "com.github.maiflai.scalatest"

compileScala.targetCompatibility = 1.8
ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    gatling {
        scala.srcDirs = ["src/gatling/scala"]
        resources.srcDirs = ["src/gatling/resources"]
    }

    test {
        scala.srcDirs = ["src/test/scala"]
        resources.srcDirs = ["src/test/resources"]
    }

}

dependencies {
    testCompile "gradle.plugin.com.github.maiflai:gradle-scalatest:0.25"
    testCompile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.12"
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.0'
    testRuntime 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.4.2'
}


gatling {
    toolVersion = '3.4.0'
    scalaVersion = '2.12.12'
    simulations = {
        include "**/*Simulation.scala"
    }
    systemProperties = ['file.encoding': 'UTF-8']
}


task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': project.version,
                'Main-Class': 'io.gatling.app.Gatling'
    }
    setArchiveBaseName project.name + '-all'
    from { 
        configurations.gatlingRuntimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'

    }
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893423/build-executable-jar-for-gatling-load-test

Comment: Unfortunately not. That didn't help me :(

Comment: [Gatling doesn't like to be launched in unofficial ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830435/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-io-gatling-app-gatling#comment112873608_63830435) With that said, there are [Gradle tricks](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/11/gradle-goodness-create-jar-artifact.html) that you can try.

Comment: You're probably right. It's frustrating but it seems it is only possible to run the simulation with gradle task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting and hours of searching for hints in the documentation, this is the build gradle snippit that did the trick:

```
configurations {
    fatJarDependencies.extendsFrom gatling
}

task fatJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: [':gatlingClasses', ':processResources']) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Preparing test',
                'Implementation-Version': '',
                'Main-Class': 'io.gatling.app.Gatling'
    }
    classifier = 'all'
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)
    from files(sourceSets.gatling.output)
    from { configurations.fatJarDependencies.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } {
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    }
    with jar
}
```

The key are the following:

**1. configurations**

```
fatJarDependencies.extendsFrom gatling
```

You need to extend `gatling`, because something like `configurations.gatlingRuntimeClasspath.collect` or `configurations.gatling.collect` does nothing in your fatJar task, even though those configurations exists (the latter at least). This is necessary in order to get the dependencies into your jar (gatling itself, scala and whatnot).

**2. dependsOn**

To be precise:

```
(type: Jar, dependsOn: [':gatlingClasses', ':processResources'])
```

Especially `gatlingClasses`, which I found through scanning the documentation page of the [gatling gradle plugin](https://gatling.io/docs/current/extensions/gradle_plugin/#default-tasks). This adds the code under `src/gatling/*`

I can run a simulation by executing the following (`-DConfig` is optional):

```
java -Dconfig.resource=myConf.conf -jar the-jar-i-created.jar -s org.comp.pckg.DemoSimulation
```

As pointed out by [George Leung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5363011/), it is also possible to generate the reports outside of the jar, if you start the comment as above (I mistakenly forgot that I added the option `-nr`). In order to customize the folder I added a `gatling.conf` in `src/gatling/resources` with the following values:

```
gatling {
  core {
    directory {
      results = "/gatling/reports"
    }
  }
}
```

This overrides the default values that you can find [here](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf).

Comment: Isn't the reason for no reports the [`-nr` flag](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/configuration/#command-line-options)?

Comment: @GeorgeLeung I edited my answer to reflect your hint. Thanks again!

Comment: So so helpful!  Thank you!